# Loading content with a tab into HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm working in a web application and I have a form that contains jQuery UI tabs. I need the same form in more than one page so I put it in a jsp file and I'm trying to get it using the .load() function.

```
$('#someDiv').load('someJsp.jsp?attribute=value',function(){});
```

It works nice in all the form, but when it loads the UI tabs it shows them one under the other, not hiding none of them.

When I click on the tab the page scrolls to the correct content but I want them to be one behind the other and switch not showing the other ones.

**Edit**

I'm trying to initialize the tabs using the function

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ disabled: [ 1, 2 ] });
```

But it doesn't works.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: when and where are you calling the tabs initialization function?

Comment: test $('#someDiv').hide() after the above code

Comment: I called the initialization function in the callback function of .load(), if I hide the div then I can't see what I'm trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below demo.

```
function go_to_page(count, url, tab) {
    // Simulate a loading of 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Write tab content
        $('#' + tab + '-content').html('<span>Content of the ' + tab + ' tab which takes a while to load</span>');
        // Hide loading image
        $('#' + tab + ' .loading').hide();
        // Add tab count
        $('#' + tab + ' .tab_count').html(new Date().getTime()).show();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8AWd/

Comment: the content of the tab is loading correctly, the problem is that it loads the content one below the other.